# Setar valor padrão para coluna de uma tabela já existente

Tags: sql-server

É possível setar valor padrão para coluna de uma tabela já existente?

Estou tentando da seguinte forma, mas sempre a coluna fica com valor nulo ao invés do valor padrão que foi informado.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSCOLUMNS C INNER JOIN SYSOBJECTS T ON C.id = T.id WHERE C.name = ('IsPreparacao') AND T.name = 'Cadastro')

BEGIN
ALTER TABLE Cadastro   
    ADD IsPreparacao bit  default 0
END
```

Já procurei na net e não achei nada que me ajude como meu problema, alguém pode me ajudar com está questão?

Muito obrigado que poder me ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta assim

```
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE Cadastro   
        ADD IsPreparacao bit NOT NULL default 0
END
```

A condição `NOT NULL` irá fazer com que os registros existentes sejam preenchidos com o valor por default. Uma *constraint* (`NOT NULL`) será criada por default.

Se quiseres definir explicitamente o nome da *constraint*, ou que a tua coluna possa ter `NULL` então podes usar a seguinte sintaxe.

```
ALTER TABLE Cadastro    
ADD IsPreparacao BIT NULL
CONSTRAINT IsPreparacaoDefault DEFAULT 0
WITH VALUES
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, conseguir resolver o problema.